# Empty GridView with dropdownlist having Datatable as it's datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, webforms

I've a form that shows empty GridView along with the Add New Button.  I have a Drop Down List in column 1 that gets populated from a database. Based on what is selected from Dropdown list, I query SQL database and populate columns 2 and 3.  I'm having trouble writing values of the dropdown list to datatable and add new row. It worked well when GridView had just textboxes but adding databound dropdownlist made it lot complex. Here is my code:

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Number">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItemNumber" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsSubjects" DataTextField="item_num" DataValueField="item_num" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Index_Changed" AutoPostBack="true" OnDataBound="addDefaultValue_DataBound">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsSubjects" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:test%>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT item_num FROM tblItemList"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqItemNumber" ValidationGroup="ValgrpCust" ControlToValidate="ddlItemNumber" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                                    
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <FooterTemplate>
             <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" 
                    onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:gridview>
```

here is my code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        SetInitialRow();
    }
}
protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddNewRowToGrid();
}

protected void addDefaultValue_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList list = sender as DropDownList;

    if (list != null)
    {
        list.Items.Insert(0, "--Select One--");
    }
}

private void SetInitialRow()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item Number", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Unit", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(string)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Item Number"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Description"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Unit"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    //Store the DataTable in ViewState
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

    Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
    Gridview1.DataBind();
}
private void AddNewRowToGrid()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;

    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //extract the TextBox values
                DropDownList ddlList1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("ddlItemNumber");
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox2");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox3");

                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                //drCurrentRow["Ro wNumber"] = i + 1;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Item Number"] = ddlList1.SelectedItem.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Description"] = box1.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Unit"] = box2.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Quantity"] = box3.Text;

                rowIndex++;
            }
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

            Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }

    //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
    SetPreviousData();
}
private void SetPreviousData()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DropDownList ddlList1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("ddlItemNumber");
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox2");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox3");

                ddlList1.SelectedItem.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Item Number"].ToString();
                box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Description"].ToString();
                box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Unit"].ToString();
                box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Quantity"].ToString();

                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void Index_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DropDownList ddlItemNumber = (DropDownList)sender;
    GridViewRow grdrDropDownRow = ((GridViewRow)ddlItemNumber.Parent.Parent);
    int index = grdrDropDownRow.RowIndex;        
    //lblMessage.Text = ddlItemNumber.SelectedItem.Text;
    DataSet myDataSet = GetData("SELECT description, unit FROM tblItemList WHERE item_num='" + ddlItemNumber.SelectedItem.Text.Trim
    () + "'");
    grdrDropDownRow.Cells[1].Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["description"].ToString(); 
    grdrDropDownRow.Cells[2].Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["unit"].ToString();
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows[i]["Item Number"] = grdrDropDownRow.Cells[1].Text;
            dt.Rows[i]["Description"] = grdrDropDownRow.Cells[2].Text;
            dt.Rows[i]["Unit"] = grdrDropDownRow.Cells[3].Text;
            dt.Rows[i]["Quantity"] = grdrDropDownRow.Cells[4].Text;
        }
    }
    SetPreviousData();
}

private DataSet GetData(string query)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any clues and your time.

Joe

Comment: As an aside, `FindControl` works on the complete `NamingContainer` control, you don't need to write: `Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl`. It works if you use it on the row: `Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl`. On that way it's much more reliable (f.e. if you change the order of columns).

Comment: What's so difficult, you don't need `Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[index].FindControl` but you can use `Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl`. The cell is not the `NamingContainer` of the controls in the `GridViewRow` but the `GridViewRow` .

Comment: Thank you. Understood. Now when I made that change I'm getting error - Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index at line 'dt.Rows[i]["Quantity"] = grdrDropDownRow.Cells[4].Text;' in method Index_Changed.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the fact that you are not using `Cells[index].FindControl` anymore. I don't understand why you are using `grdrDropDownRow.Cells[4].Text` there. You are using TemplateFields with controls, you cannot get or set the cell's Text with `TemplateFields`. You have to get the refercne tio the controls.

Comment: My head is spinning.  Ok. I grdrDropDownRow.Cells[4].Text to dt.Rows[i]["Quantity"] = dt.Rows[i]["Quantity"].ToString();  to get the refernce to the textbox control in Quantity column. Now I'm getting new error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at line box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Description"].ToString(); in method SetPreviousData().